# Understanding member initializer lists

Tags: c++, qt, class

This is the auto-generated function code in Qt mainwindow.cpp.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

}
```

Would this be the same thing?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    QMainWindow = parent;
    ui = new Ui::MainWindow;
}
```

Comment: Nope, they're not the same; not by far. Though they are similar.

Comment: Does your second version compile?

Comment: My guess is not. (that was for the compiling question).

Comment: QMainWindow is a parent class, so you should initialize it in the list after the constructor. ui, as far as I remember, is an object created in the class so you may initialize it in the body of the constructor.

Comment: @rpsml, pointer it seems. I absolutely can't remember if it's going to be zero-initialized or left with garbage upon construction, so I'm not sure if the assignment happens twice in this case. But it isn't pretty ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, I agree with you. I was too short in my comment. What I meant was, "You may initialize it in the body... but it is as ugly as it can be and you may have a performance penalty".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. I believe `QMainWindow` is a base class, so the `QMainWindow=parent` is not a replacement at all. As for the `ui` assignment. In the first case it will be initialized with `new Ui::MainWindow`, whereas in the second snippet it will be assigned after initialization. In case of complex object it may incur significant performance penalty and it may also be impossible to properly initialize the object after constructring.